# Taking data from specific columns in a dataset

Tags: python

I need to take data from only 3 columns in my dataset, how do I do this? I am trying to make a correlation graph. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

crimedata = pd.read_csv('MasterFileCSV.csv')
crime_df = pd.DataFrame(crimedata)

plt.matshow(crime_df.corr())
plt.show
```

Comment: `crimedata` is a lready a dataframe. Instead, just `crime_df = crimedata[['column1', 'col2', 'col3']]`

Comment: Hmm that didn't work either. I get the error "KeyError: ('Homicide Convictions', 'Robbery Convicions', 'Criminal Damage Convictions')" which are the columns I'm trying to use

Comment: check the column names. Posting the stacktrace can also help